# optimize number of record insert in to crm using kingswaysoft

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

i am trying insert more than 1 million record from sql server to crm it takes 2 hours for inserting 50,000 records is this normal or can we optimize this one because i dont have knowledge on crm before any suggestion is highly appriciate

Comment: You need to clarify what CRM system you are using, and explain in detail the method you are using to load data from SQL to that system.

Comment: I am using kingswaysoft plugin in ssis to extract data from sql server to crm

Comment: What CRM system?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft microsoft dynamics crm

Answer (score 1):

Bulk load API & multi-threading gives us more powerful integration data flow in Dynamics CRM + KingswaySoft combo.

From Kingswaysoft FAQ:

> **How do I maximize the throughput when writing data to Microsoft Dynamics?**
>
> The easiest way to achieve a better writing performance when working with Microsoft Dynamics 365 is to use a Batch Size along with the Multi-threaded writing (available since v9.0) which are two single configurations in the CRM destination component. However, it's important to choose the right combination of Batch Size and the number of threads used to achieve the best possible performance.

[Read more](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/faq)